# How to retrive all AWS SQS queue messages in lumen without dispatching

Tags: amazon-sqs, lumen, laravel-queue, lumen-5.4

I am trying to fetch the AWS SQS queue messages using lumen Queue worker and SQS queue messages will be created by other API's which is on other end. How can I retrieve all the messages from queue and process it.

I have created the job and installed the AWS sdk package into the lumen but it is not calling the handle written into the Job.

Can anyone please guide me step by step to sort out the problem

Comment: Have you considered creating a supervisor that points to `artisan queue:listen sqs ...`

Comment: I have two server one for dispatching the queue data and second for retrieving but dispatching is successfully done at the 1st server but for pull the queue data second servers handle function is not get call